# ZSH which/whence alias for type -p not identifying node

Tags: shell, zsh

We have code to check for a node install:

```
which="type -p"
if [ $SHELL = "/bin/zsh" ]; then
    which="whence"
fi
# make sure that node exists
node=`$which node 2>&1`
ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ] || ! [ -x "$node" ]; then
<"This error code is returned">
```

But when I run this with ZSH (OhMyZsh) it returns a 127 (does not exist). Commenting out the `which="whence"` lets it run fine.

Without removing the whole aliasing bit is there any way to have ZSH play along with this? Ideally I'd like to make a change on my end to make this work rather than modifying this code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, you run `$node` and it appears that you’ve tried to run command whose name is `node --alias-args` which does not exist?

If this is true, change the third line to use `whence -p`: it has the same output as `type -p` in bash. If not, please, explain when this code is returned.

**Update**: I do not know what was done in ohmyzsh (though I have not a single idea how to make a builtin not found) so just try to rewrite the code in this way:

```
# At the very top
if [ -n $ZSH_VERSION ] ; then
    emulate -L zsh
endif
<...>
which="type -p"
if [ -n $ZSH_VERSION ] ; then
    which=( whence -p ) # Changes variable type as well
endif
node=`$which node 2>&1`
if (( ? )) || ! test -x $node ; then
<...>
```

Comment: Edited in the next bit of code (Sorry about that). Whence -p still returns the same error when I run this.

Comment: It is strange. I would understand `$which node` running with error 127 when it is set to `type -p`: unlike bash, zsh treats this as one word and `"type -p"` command does not exist (use `$=which` to work around or use arrays which are as well supported by bash) (behavior is default, there is an option to make zsh behave like bash). BTW, testing for zsh is `! test -z $ZSH_VERSION`, not `$SHELL`.